# ProgressBar com Timer

Tags: c#

Tenho uma aplicação com uma SplashScreen onde tenho a `ProgressBar barraProgresso`. O objetivo é que assim que ela estiver 100% carregada, abrir outro form e fechar a Splash.

O problema é que quando faltam uns 20% para concluir, a janela trava, abre o form seguinte e logo após já o fecha, fechando também a aplicação.

Código:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (barraProgresso.Value != 100)
        {
            barraProgresso.PerformStep();
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            new FormOpcaoAcesso().Visible = true;
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    private void SplashScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
        timer1.Interval = 20;
        barraProgresso.Maximum = 100;
        barraProgresso.Step = 1;
        timer1.Tick  += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    }
```

Vale lembrar que eu quero realmente fechar a splash, e não dar um `.Hide()`, por exemplo.

Comment: Basicamente, vc quer enganar o user?

Comment: "o sistema está abrindo muito rápido, vou colocar uma barra só pra atrasar ele" rsrs mas então... provável que sua Splash seja o form principal da aplicação, tem que ver o código desde o método main até o form que deve ficar aberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, você dois problemas aí:

1. A barra para de carregar nos ~80% e já executa como se estivesse cheia.
2. Fechar a splashscreen fecha também o main thread (resultando no fechamento de todos os processos envolvidos).

O problema **1.** "não tem solução", foi assim que o windows foi construído. O que acontece é que a animação da barra enchendo demora mais para chegar nos 100% do que o `.Value` dela em si. Ou seja, se ela estiver com `.Value = 0`, e você atribuir o `.Value` para 100, ela vai demorar algo como 1 segundo para chegar, visualmente, ao 100%.

É exatamente isso que esta acontecendo com o timer, ele coloca a barra em 100%, mas a animação ainda ta no 80%, porem, como o valor dela já é 100%, ele continua executando o código que você escreveu.

Para resolver isso, você pode criar um método assíncrono que da um delay de mais ou menos 1000 milissegundos e depois abrir a nova form:

```
private async void RunAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    new FormOpcaoAcesso().Show();
    this.Close(); // Ainda vai fechar o programa
}
```

E chamar esse método assíncrono do teu método `Tick`.

Já o problema **2.** é mais simples. O problema, como apontado pelo [Rovann Linhalis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/69359/rovann-linhalis), é que a Form SplashScreem é a principal do programa. Para resolver isso, vá no arquivo `Program.cs` e edite a chamada do método `.Run` para que, ao invés de rodar com uma `Form`, ele rode com um `ApplicationContext`. Porem você vai querer que esse ApplicationContext seja acessível de outras classes, portanto vou sugerir que você crie ele como uma propriedade public static com get public e set privado.

O código que vai estar no `Program.cs` vai ser tipo assim:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    App = new ApplicationContext();
    App.MainForm = new SplashForm();

    Application.Run(App);
}

public static ApplicationContext App { get; private set; }
```

Aí, quando você for fechar a splashscreen:

```
//esse pedaço de código vai dentro da Form que você quer fechar (no caso a SplashScreen)
private async void RunAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    var form = new FormOpcaoAcesso();
    form.Show();

    Program.App.MainForm = form;
    this.Close();
}
```

Done :D
Seus dois problemas estão resolvidos, lembrando que usar um delay, geralmente não é uma boa ideia, porque não é confiável que todos os computadores que o teu programa está rodando conseguem executar o código no tempo certo. E eu ainda acho que você está enganando o usuário que nem o Marchelo Uchimura comentou e isso não é legal cara, kk se foi um pedido do professor(a), tenta dar uma função para a splash screen ou faça ela muito rápida kkk.